# Display pages viewed to a member

Tags: solspace-tracker, tracking

I wish to show to a logged in member, a list of pages they have recently viewed.

I have looked into the default Tracking module and Solspace tracker, but these all seem to just work to display on a particular entry or in the CP, rather than displaying on say an account page for a member.

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might find Rob Sanchez' [Mo' Variables](https://github.com/rsanchez/mo_variables) useful for this situation. The add-on adds variables for `{last_page_visited}`, `{one_page_ago}`, `{two_pages_ago}`, etc. up to 5 pages back.